# How can I decrease the font size of incoming messages on the Samsung Galaxy Note permanently?

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note, fonts

After the regular update of my Samsung Galaxy Note to Android 4.1.2, the font size in the messaging section is quite oversized.

By using the volume keys I can indeed reduce the font, but this setting is not saved.

My device is not rooted.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @ZnewmaN: Nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps download a font from the Google play store? I've seen some fonts packs up there.

e.g.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.develop.plugin.font&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5kZXZlbG9wLnBsdWdpbi5mb250Il0.

Some of these will more than likely require your device be rooted.

Or you can change the size of your phone's font. To do that go to settings\display\font,
You should be ably to manipulate the font.

Wasn't much to go on so I hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, the global font size setting affects the font of the messages. Putting this on the smallest option unfortunately makes other text difficult to read. Thank you anyway. I think I have to live with it for now.

Answer (score 4):

I notice this annoyance too.

Looks like the best solution is to enable volume key text resizing, and leave it enabled.

Once you disable it, the Messages app resets the text size to the huge (on the Galaxy Note, that is) font/bubble size.

This won't be noticeable on other phones; the real cause is that the GNote is big, which is what all GNote owners like about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Peculiar. On my GS3 on 4.1.1, it saves the font size (i.e. after closing and opening it again, it is the same size as I set it with the volume key.

This may wipe your messages (find a way to back them up if you'd like them), but have you tried clearing the Messaging app's data in Application Manager -> All?

Comment: I deleted the data as suggested. The messages are retained, the settings are not. However, the font size is reset to extra-large after a reboot.

Comment: Shucks! :( Hmm...I find it very peculiar behavior. If it ever bothers you to no end one day, I might suggest ChompSMS as an alternative. Very clean and easy to use and with a TON of customization options. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a GS4 vers. 4.3

I had the same problem. But the use of the volume key solves my issue.  Resized using 
volume key while in the messaging mode.  Viola!

Comment: He has tried resizing using volume keys but the setting isn't saved, I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue on a Note 3.

I was resizing the font by "pinching" the screen. It would not save; I'm stuck with the huge font.

So, I used the size volume key instead to resize the font. Now, everything works fine.

Comment: This was on a note 3